# Does a name exist for the parenthesis after new()?

Tags: c#

I wanted to inquire more about a construct I occasionally see in some C# code; however, I don't know the name. I apologize if this is a duplicate; however, its very hard to search for things without knowing their name.

The construct is as follows:

```
Person me = new Person(){ Name = "Aelphaeis" } ;
```

Is there a special name for assigning fields/properties like this?

Comment: Yes. It's called an object initializer.

Comment: Btw, you can ommit the empty parenthesis when using an object initializer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called *object initializer*. For instance let we have a class called `Customer`, whose definition is the following one:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could instantiate an object of type `Customer` like below:

```
Customer customer = new Customer 
{ 
    ID = 0, 
    FirstName="firstName", 
    LastName="lastName", 
    Age = 20 
};
```

In a few words it's another way to instantiate an object.

> What happens behind the scenes, when we use an object initializer?

The default empty constructor of `Customer` is called:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

and then the propertie's setter's are called *in the order they have written in the object initializer*:

```
customer.ID = 0;
customer.FirstName = "firstName";
customer.LastName = "lastName";
customer.Age = 20;
```

Furthermore, a notion close to *object initializer* is the *collection initializer*.

Instead of writing this:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add(1);
numbers.Add(2);
numbers.Add(3);
numbers.Add(4);
```

we could write this:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

which is definetely more compact that the initial version and I would say also more expressive. In the above example, we used a *collection initializer*.

> What happens behind the scenes, when we use a collection initializer?

If we take the last example, it happens exactly this:

```
// Create the a new list
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

// Add one element after the other, in the order they appear in the
// collection initializer, using the Add method.
numbers.Add(1);
numbers.Add(2);
numbers.Add(3);
numbers.Add(4);
```

For more information about *object and collection initializers*, please visit this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Last but not least, I would like to point out that *object and collection initializers* got introduced in C# 3.0. Unfortunately, If you had to write an application in days of C# 2.0 you hadn't this feature available.

Comment: A *collection initializer* (the one on your example) and an *object initializer* (the one on OP's example) are not the same thing. It's important to stress the difference between the two.

Comment: Yeah I will do it right now. Thanks for mentioning this

Comment: Great answer; however, I think it can be enhanced for future inqueries by adding an example of philippe's comment. (new StudentName {FirstName="Craig", LastName="Playstead", ID=116};)

Answer (score 2):

This is called an Object Initializer. There is also a similar pattern for collections called a Collection Initializer.

Here is a basic example:

```
var widgetA = new Widget
{
    WidgetId = "1",
    WidgetName = "My Widget"
};
```

You can also call a constructor while using a object initialization:

```
// a constructor that takes an id for a parameter
var widgetB = new Widget("1")
{
    WidgetId = "1",
    WidgetName = "My Widget"
};
```

There is also the collection intializer (which can also be combines with an object initializer):

```
   var widgetList = new List<Widget>
    {
        new Widget {WidgetId = "1", WidgetName = "A"},
        new Widget {WidgetId = "2", WidgetName = "B"},
        new Widget {WidgetId = "3", WidgetName = "C"},
    };
```

You can also nest object or collection initializers

```
var widget = new Widget
{
    WidgetId = "1",
    WidgetName = "My Widget",
    ChildWidget = new Widget
    {
        WidgetId = "2",
        WidgetName = "I'm a Child Widget"
    }
};
```

This pattern can also be used for anonymous objects:

```
var anonymousObject = new 
{
    Id = "1",
    Name = "My Anonymous Object",
};
```

You can use an abuse the pattern in many ways, but at a certain point it can start getting pretty hard to read.

One important thing to note is that object assignments are made after the object constructor is called. So any value set through the object initialization won't be available in the constructor.

Further reading:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

Comment: I think this is because setting the properties of an object and adding elements to a list are two different things? Please correct me, if I'm wrong here..

Comment: Ok, technically one is called an object initializer and one is called a collection initializer, but could the point be made as an edit, rather than a downvote?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't actually downvoted your answer^^

Comment: @sekky You are correct, one is object initialization and the other is collection initialization, but that distinction alone hardly merits a downvote without an explanation from the downvoter(s).

Answer (score 2):

It's called object initializer. You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

You can do the same for collections (Collection Initializer)

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>
{
    new Cat(){ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 },
    new Cat(){ Name = "Whiskers", Age=2 },
    new Cat(){ Name = "Sasha", Age=14 }
};
```

Personally, I don't like it, for two reasons,

1. if a exception is throw inside the object initializer, you don't have the exact line number where it occurred. I would use it for simple initializations, but not for some complex initialization.
2. I find it harder to read (but that is a personal preference)

Comment: You make an excellent point about complex initialization.  That said, it is far more likely that the exception would (or at least should) occur downstream in the constructor/invoked functions of the object being initialized if it is anything more than just that, "newing" up the object. +1 for an appropriate cautioning.